# pouchdb alldocs get nosql attachment

Tags: base64, blob, attachment, pouchdb, cloudant

I have a piece of angular2 + pouchdb code that queries cloudant and fetches documents with their attachments. The console log of the returned doc looks like the below

```
{"type":"some_doc"},"_attachments":{"logo.png":{"digest":"md5-UK7aKiZSqQ6Xljz4wmUMkw==","content_type":"image/png","data":"iVBO....CCGE
```

Truncated the data...

I'm now trying to display the image in a list of items with

```
<img [src]=doc.some.path>
```

The challenge I'm facing is that I can't dynamically reach the data element to fetch the *blob* and invoke the

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

All the posts I found are either very old and about alldocs not supporting attachment get, or hardcoding blobs in sample code.

Please help.

Thanks,
Elvis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is best expressed [here](http://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/2a5f98a66c9fe3ae3532). In summary:

- call the PouchDB `db.getAttachment` function to return the image as a Blob object
- call `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` to turn the blob into a URL consumable by an image tag
- attach the URL to the `img` tag's `src` attribute

Comment: I've gone through this before, the problem here is that I'll need to make a db.getAttachment call to database again for every record, whereas I've already done a db.alldocs({attachments=true}) and fetched all attachments for all users. How to reuse the blob in the json is the question.

Comment: Or else, since db.getAttachment requires two parameters namely, _id of the doc and fileName, how can I determine the dynamically named fileName of an attachment in the database ?